# Markdown: smaller images sizes not supported by GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, image-scaling

I want to downsize some of my images in my [README.md](https://github.com/rasbt/matplotlib_gallery#quadratic_decbound1) on GitHub and it works fine in my Markdown editor using something like

```
![](./images/my_img.png =400x)
```

However, when I upload it to GitHub, the Markdown viewer seems to not like it. Any suggestions or ideas how I can downsize the images without reducing the resolution of the images themselves?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Github doesn't apply the **style** attribute but obeys the **width** and **height**. So for github you can use the following HTML tag directly in the markdown:

```
<img src="url" alt="alt text" width="whatever" height="whatever">
```

Comment: Thanks. The only challenge is then to get the aspect ratio right

Comment: Drop the height parameter to preserve the aspect ratio automatically.

Answer (score 13):

You can use HTML syntax for the image directly in markdown

```
## Markdown Header

This is a markdown paragraph. Etc.

<img src="url" alt="alt text" style="width:whatever;height:whatever">
```

**Update:** As tzolov notes, GitHub doesn't actually permit inline styles. His technique does work, though.

Comment: is there a way I can set the height relative to the width (and vice versa), would make it easier, since the dimensions for the different images might be/are different

Comment: alas not. (well technically there is a way using the `background-image` property, but it's way more trouble than it's worth in this case.)

Comment: Um.. not sure if I understand @SebastianRaschka right, but simply specifying *only* width or height should scale the other dimension accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't work on github, image is there, but in its original size, github seems to filter out the `style` attribute...

Comment: Doesn't work, @tzolov's answer should be marked as correct one

Comment: `style=""` does not work in github. The post form @tzolov should appear higher.